# Infinite loop - ignore error and continue?

Tags: php

I create the code for the infinite loop like this:

```
<?php
    while(1) {
        "some code"
    }
?>
```

Now the problem is that some times the internet connection goes down. Sometimes fatal errors occur. That's why the loop process stops. I want to run the loop forever - ignore the all the errors, warnings and notices, and run the loop forever. How do I do this?

Comment: Internet connection go down -> Not possible, fatal errors occurs -> no... they are not errors, in short I see no good reason why you would need an infinite loop unless and until you have a condition inside the loop to break the loop and end

Comment: Don't do this on the server side. Use Javascript / AJAX instead (in the browser, on the client side).

Comment: Are you trying to daemonize PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can increase server timeout for running script

**in php.ini file**

```
max_execution_time=-1
```

**PHP**

```
if(set_time_limit (-1))
{
    while(1)
    {
        "some code";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "error occured";
}
```